# Convert a floating point number to an integer except math.floor()

Tags: python

Is there any way to convert a floating point number in Python to an integer except `math.floor()`?

I have already tried `math.floor()`, but I am getting an error says:

```
Cannot import math
```

Any other way?

Comment: Ah...`int(1.23456)`?

Comment: Use `int`. However, if you cannot `import math` there's something seriously wrong with your Python installation that *needs* fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `int()` function

```
print int(5.3) # "5"
```

For more [info](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Use `int(3.14)`
- `import math` then `math.floor(3.14)` or `math.ceil(3.14)` (depending on which way you want to round) (you said this doesn't work but I'll leave it for reference)
- `x = x - x % 1` or `x -= x % 1`